# How do I find Safari on a Mac?

Tags: macos, internet, browser

I just bought a Mac Mini after using PCs for a decade plus. I've configured with the Mac Mini setup assistant. It finally confirms I'm connected to the internet.

I can find no browser to surf the internet with. I've read all Mac Mini's come with Safari. How do I find Safari on Mac Mini?

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to open Safari:

- If your installation of OS X wasn't customized, you will find Safari in the dock – the big bar with the application icons at the bottom. Look for the Safari icon.

  [image]
- Click on the Spotlight icon in the top right (or press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>) and enter "Safari".

  [image]
- Click on the Finder icon, go to the menu and select *Go » Applications* (or press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>), and look for Safari  there.

  [image]